# C++: unique_ptr vs auto_ptr, and advantages of unique_ptr over auto_ptr?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, auto-ptr

I do not fully understand the benefits of `unique_ptr` over `auto_ptr`, or I am not yet fully convinced why we need to use `unique_ptr`.

I see the following differences.

1) `unique_ptr` supports arrays and thus the `unique_ptr` destructor calls `delete []` for arrays whereas the `auto_ptr` destructor calls only `delete`.

2) `std::move()` has to be used instead of directly copying in case of `unique_ptr`. But what advantage do we get with `std::move()`? I will try to explain as below.

```
auto_ptr <int> p1 (new int);
auto_ptr <int> p2 = p1;    // Now p1 is NULL and p2 exists with value of p1

unique_ptr <int> p1 (new int);
unique_ptr <int> p2 = std::move(p1);    // Now p1 is NULL and p2 exists with value of p1
```

so what is the advantage we are going to get with this?

3) I read on the Internet that `unique_ptr` can be used in containers. But if I understood correctly, this is not the great thing of `unique_ptr`. Container function semantics are changed so now a days, copying is not getting done inside of the container functions. But how is this the great thing of `unique_ptr`? Now that container functions are changed, why we cannot use `auto_ptr` in containers?

Comment: The advantage of having to move is that you're *moving* it to move ownership instead of copying it to move ownership. The latter makes so little sense.

Comment: The main advantage is that the additions made to `unique_ptr` make it safe to use in STL containers. `auto_ptr` is not container-safe.

Comment: @RemyLebeau : The same thing I mentioned in my 3rd point. We can use unique_ptr now in containers because container functions are modified (to not use copying). So we can also use auto_ptr now in containers.

Comment: My understanding is that `auto_ptr` is still not container safe in C++11. `unique_ptr` was created to address all of the shortcomings of `auto_ptr`, and `auto_ptr` itself has not been changed.

Comment: No, you can't use `auto_ptr` in containers, it's still not safe.

Comment: I believe it would be correct to say that C++11 containers will make use of move actions _if possible_ but with `auto_ptr` its still not possible.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is not container safe because it does not support proper copy/move sematics that containers expect. It can steal ownership at times when stealing is not desired, thus objects might get freed prematurely. `unique_ptr` does not suffer from that problem. Another advantage of `unique_ptr` is that it supports a custom `deleter`, which makes it possible to have it manage resources that are not allocated with `new` or `new[]`. `auto_ptr` does not support that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, `auto_ptr` has/had magic constructors, like `auto_ptr(auto_ptr &other) {...}`, which would behave like:

- First copying from `other` instance.
- Then null-constructing `other` instance.

Nowadays compilers support `std::move(...)`, hence no need for "copy-style" constructor that did in reality "move", but to support old code, `auto_ptr` was left unchanged, and instead got deprecated (to be removed later).

`unique_ptr` forces you to be explicit about transferring ownership, so it is visible and clear in the code. With `auto_ptr` it is too easy to get silent transfers of ownership and when reading the code it's not always clear whether ownership is transferred, and if it is, whether it was intended by the author of the code or is a bug!  When you see a `unique_ptr` used with `std::move` it is obvious that the intention is to transfer ownership.

`unique_ptr` properly supports move semantics, so it only allows ownership transfer from temporaries and moved objects (i.e. [rvalues](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)). Containers can detect if a type is "move aware" and act appropriately.  `auto_ptr` does not know about move semantics, and will transfer ownership from lvalues or rvalues, so containers *think* it's a normal copyable object, but it doesn't behave like one because it modifies its source when copying.

`auto_ptr` was useful when used carefully, but it was too easy to misuse it and write dangerous code. It is time for it to die. `unique_ptr` supports everything `auto_ptr` can do, but is safe by default (you have to try harder to use it wrong) and also has extra features like custom deleters and array support.

Comment: Why do you think the committee didn't choose the option of enhancing `auto_ptr`?  For example they simply added move ctor to `std::ifstream` instead of defining something like `std::movable_ifstream`.

Comment: @nodakai Adding move functions to `auto_ptr` doesn't help unless you remove the weird copy semantics, which will break compatibility.

Comment: Exactly. You can make `fstream` movable and no existing code breaks, noone was writing code that moved `fstream` objects before. But if you change `auto_ptr` from being weird to having conventional C++11 move semantics all the existing code that (intentionally or accidentally) relied on it being weird will break.

Comment: Hmm, so you folks really dislike `auto_ptr(auto_ptr&)`...  I would be happy enough if I had STL-compatible `auto_ptr` with custom deleter